# Maths Operations on Columns from Different Data Frames

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I have two data frames, imported through Pandas from Fama French and Yahoo. I am trying to compare column values from the two data frames (more specifically, subtract one from the other), but a value error occurs whenever I try doing so. The data frames have different indexing and I don't know how to take this factor into account (I'm quite new to python & pandas).

Here is the code in question:

```
start, end = dt.datetime.now()-dt.timedelta(days=60*30), dt.datetime.now()
f = data.DataReader('F-F_Research_Data_Factors', 'famafrench',  start, end)[0]
s = data.get_data_yahoo('aapl', start, end)
s = s.resample('M', how='last')
s['returns'] = s['Adj Close'].pct_change()
```

Ideally, I would like to create a series with row values = f['RF'] - s['returns']

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the dataframes always the same length?  Can you post examples?

Comment: One of the sets has 61 rows, while the other 43... I suppose I would only like to perform the operation on the first 43? However, ultimately, I'm building a function that performs this operation on different data frames, so It'd be great to find a more universally applicable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `f.index`

```
f.index = f.index.to_datetime() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

f['RF'] - s['returns']
```

Comment: thats what im talking about. here the dataframe can be aligned. go ahead and accept this answer. BTW I hope you dont downvoted me!

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Ask yourself, how you could possibly define a difference between two matrices when they have a different size?

First thing to do, is to match the two dataframes on a commmon value (say the date). Then you will be able to do any operation you want

Comment: Hi Noobie, ultimately I'm trying to find a more universally applicable function method that takes in a data frame (matrix) and subtracts its column values from those of another matrix. More specifically, I'm trying to compare stock returns to the risk free rate, to find risk premium... This would also mean that I have to make sure that the rows in each of the two matrices being compared are linked to corresponding months.. which might not always be the case... Could you suggest any way to approach this issue?

Comment: If worst comes to worst, i'll just bypass this issue by taking average of the two columns (risk free, and stock return) first, and then calc the difference... however that would make the results a bit less accurate, which is why i'm trying to avoid this approach